# Проблема с библиотекой vk_api

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api, библиотеки

Есть код, который должен возвращать кикнутых пользователей в беседу:

```py
import time
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkChatEventType

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='тут был токен с доступом к сообщениям с моей страницы')
vk = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
print("Антикик запущен")

#основной цикл
while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(3)
        for event in longpoll.listen():
            if event.type == VkChatEventType.USER_KICKED:
                vk.messages.addChatUser(chat_id=event.chat_id, user_id=event.user_id)
                print('Пользователя вернул в беседу')
    except vk_api.exceptions.Captcha:
        print('Нужна капча!')
        continue
    except vk_api.exceptions.AccessDenied:
        print('Доступ запрещён')
        continue
```

Но при выполнении кода, во время какого либо действия в беседе, if начинает игнорироваться напрочь и в любом случае исполняет код внутри.

Comment: Ваше приложение прошло модерацию? ВК изменили политику в отношении API сообщений. [Подробнее](https://vk.com/dev/messages_api)

Comment: Я использовал другое приложение для получения токена.